# Two parts Homepage like tumblr start page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

i bet everyone of you has seen www.tumblr.com
right on the registration page on the bottom you see the '30 reasons...' link that slides the complete page up and reveals a second one.

i found ways to do this with putting two sides into one and just scrolling to the second part, but tumblr seems to have 2 different pages there that swap somehow with a slide effect.

im pretty sure it is done with some jQuery but i have not found any more information about how to achieve something like this.

it is a question out of pure interest because i really love the effect =)

it would be great if someone would give me a hint how to do something like that.

thanks in advance, 
sebastian

Comment: You could use jQuery accordion, or a slide effect with two divs with show/hide. Or replace divs with jQuery with a fade and slide effect. There's a bunch of ways.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is indeed a nice effect. It's a bit of a combination of CSS and javascript really. I would use jQuery for sure. I've knocked up a little jsFiddle to show you how it can be done:

http://jsfiddle.net/SufZD/

Comment: can't just yet - i need more reputation, im new to stackoverflow =)

Comment: Ah yeah, no problem. Get stuck in it's a great site. It's definitely given me a lot!